# Why the alamofire always return failure case?

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to get the data from the url. I give two cases in it success and failure. But the always give me failure case. I don't why it always return failure case to me.. Thanks in advance.

## RegisterTwo

In this class I am trying to download the data.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class RegisterTwo {

    private static var _businessName = [String]()

   public static var businessName: [String] {
        if _businessName.isEmpty == true {
            _businessName = ["Line of business"]
        }
        return _businessName
    }

    func downloadLineOfBusiness(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {

        let lineOfBusinessURL = URL(string: LINE_OF_BUSINESS_URL)!
        Alamofire.request(lineOfBusinessURL).responseJSON { (response) in
            let result = response.result

            switch(result) {

            case.success(_):

                if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                    // results
                    if let results = dict["results"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] , results.count > 0 {

                        // name
                        if let name = results[0]["name"] as? String {

                            RegisterTwo._businessName.append("\(name)")
                        }

                        if results.count > 1 {

                            for x in 1..<results.count {
                                if let name = results[x]["name"] as? String {
                                    RegisterTwo._businessName.append("\(name)")
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        print(RegisterTwo._businessName)

                    }

                    // set the success value true
                    UserDefaults.standard.setIsSuccessLineOfBusiness(value: true)

                }

                break

            case.failure(_):

                // set the success value false
                UserDefaults.standard.setIsSuccessLineOfBusiness(value: false)
                print("Failure occured")

                break

            }


            completed()
        }

    }
}
```

## SplashVC

I call the function here.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        checkInternet()
    }

    func checkInternet() {
        if currentReachabilityStatus == .reachableViaWiFi {
            print("User is connected to the internet via wifi.")

                self.registerTwo.downloadLineOfBusiness {

                    if self.isSuccessLineOfBusiness() {

                        self.perform(#selector(SplashVC.showVC), with: nil, afterDelay: 2)

                    } else {

                        self.alertBox(title: "Internet Error", message: "\nConnection Problem. Please reopen the app.")

                    }

                }

        }else if currentReachabilityStatus == .reachableViaWWAN{
            print("User is connected to the internet via WWAN.")

                self.registerTwo.downloadLineOfBusiness {

                    if self.isSuccessLineOfBusiness() {

                        self.perform(#selector(SplashVC.showVC), with: nil, afterDelay: 2)

                    } else {

                        self.alertBox(title: "Internet Error", message: "\nConnection Problem. Please reopen the app.")

                    }

                }

        } else {
            print("There is no internet connection")
            alertBox(title: "Internet Error", message: "\nNo internet connection.")
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the content of `LINE_OF_BUSINESS_URL`

Comment: In case of failure, what about logging the error returned?

Comment: line-of-business/list/?format=json is the url end

Comment: AILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 1." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 1.})

Comment: So the JSON doesn't seem valid. Open that URL in Safari or any web browser, or with POSTMAN, and check its value with a JSON validator online.

Comment: okey thanks, the issue come from the link thanks for the help

Comment: If you call `.validate()` before `.responseJSON()`, it will do some additional checking of the response. I bet the status code is not 200, and it's often better to detect that via `.validate()` rather than JSON parsing problems arising from what is likely a HTML message from your server describing some problem.